# react-native-tvos Undefined symbol: ___darwin_check_fd_set_overflow

Tags: react-native-ios

So i'm just trying setup a test app using https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tvos using these commands verbatim

[image]

but keep getting this error

[image]

Comment: Check out this thread and answer: [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30231#issuecomment-738674682)